# Emacs same keymap different command

Tags: emacs, lisp

I was wondering if there was a way to say map

s-Y to two different commands.

I was thinking I wanted s-Y to bring up the terminal in a split window that was lower,
then bring up the bash then by then changing focus to the new window so

```
(defun bash-window ()
  (interactive)  
  (split-window-below)
  (other-window 1)
  (shell)
  )
```

Then with the same command terminate the shell process and un split the lower window is there a way I can do this with lisp, it appears lisp does not hold state in emacs lisp programming.... unless I am incorrect about that.

Comment: I don't know exactly how to do this, but wouldn't it be:  bind s-Y to an elisp function A, which does the splitting and stuff, and also re-binds s-Y to map to function B.  Function B closes the split, and rebinds s-Y back to function A.   .emacs initally binds s-Y to function A.

Comment: @Dave, that's actually really clever -- I'll have to put that trick up my sleeve for next time! XD (But seriously, that's cool.)

Comment: ;; fix the reverse function aka undo function
(defun bash-window ()
  (global-set-key (kbd "s-Y") 'bash-window-undo)
  (interactive)  
  (split-window-below)
  (other-window 1)
  (shell)
  )

(defun bash-window-undo ()
  (global-set-key (kbd "s-Y") 'bash-window)
  (interactive)
  (other-window -1)
  (delete-other-windows-vertically)
  )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not write a new function that does both, and then bind that?

Emacs Lisp (and most Lisps in general) *does* have state, you just need to know where to look for it.  (This is CLisp's greatest departure from being purely functional.)

For example,

```
(setq bash-window-active nil)

(defun bash-window nil
    (interactive)
    (if bash-window-active
        (function-to-reverse-those-performed-below)
      (progn
        (split-window-below)
        (other-window 1)
        (shell)
        (setq bash-window-active t)))

(global-set-key "\C-cb" 'bash-window)
```

Comment: Wow thanks you guys are both great this works even better thanks!

Comment: Btw are there any more ways I can have state variables that hold their value while in a function ? that is how can I encapsulate, bash-window-active nil to the bash-window function?

Comment: You can use `let` expressions to introduce local bindings (which can be mutated with `setq` and thus used as variables). Documentation [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/Parts-of-let-Expression.html).

Comment: @ChrisBarrett `let` uses dynamic binding by default, so you cannot hold state between invocations of a function.  Unless you specify `lexical-binding` (with Emacs 24).

Comment: True, I always do the lexical-binding boilerplate so I forgot about that point. :) @Mike: You might prefer to use `lexical-let` in such a case.